# Securing application passwords

Tags: security, passwords, password-protection, password-encryption

What are best practices in securing passwords that are using in application? For example password for database and other services.

- plain text password in VCS
- crypted password in VCS, provide decrypting key on application launch
- a tool for securely managing secrets, like [Vault](https://www.hashicorp.com/products/vault/)
- ???

Comment: Since you don't say what the passwords that you have are protecting, this question is not answerable.

Comment: @ArtjomB. what about "For example password for database" from question?

Comment: OK, who do you want to protect them from and why? Isn't the user of an application supposed to access the data of the application?

Comment: If password is stored in VCS, than who has access to VCS also will have access to database, I want what only 1-2 persons will know the password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all comes down to two options:

1. configure application with passwords on deployment. E.g. properties file, command-line parameters or env variables
2. pull passwords from secure password repository

And one rule:

Accessing production passwords should require the same privileges as modifying production application that uses that passwords. E.g. passwords should be available only to application and deployment script of that application.

Details really depend on your infrastructure and requirements.